# How to get a portable LTE modem + wifi access point that uses replaceable (AA/AAA) batteries?

Tags: modem, access-point, 3g

There is a lot of devices, that act as a 3G/4G modems and access points. Their weak part is that they use internal battery, which is expensive/not easily replaceable.

The ideal solution would be to have a device, that takes power from 2 or more AA batteries, that are trivial to recharge in bulk or buy at the nearest shop. The combined power of 2 AA batteries is in order of 4000 mAh, which is more than typical power of batteries included in available modems.

I tried of an hour to find any such device, and I failed. Is some reason, why such device doesn't exist, or I simply missed one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confronting the collective intelligence of the humanity can cause serious disappointment. :-( In your place I tried to buy a cheap battery frame, and buyed a modem with a simple 5V usb connector. A rechargeable battery gives 1.2V, 4 or 5 of them in a frame could give you what you want, and probably you can find such thing in ebay (or even in your local Conrad (or any electronic shop)). A good battery recharger can cost around 30 euro ($45).